# Find out number of characters in a UTF-8 string in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, utf-8

I am trying to find out a string length when the string is stored in UTF-8.
I tried following approach:

```
String str = "मेरा नाम";
Charset UTF8_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
byte[] abc = str.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET);
int length = abc.length;
```

This gives me length of the byte array, but not number of characters in the string.

I found a website which shows both UTF-8 string length and byte length.
https://mothereff.in/byte-counter
Let's say my string is मेरा नाम, then I should get string length as 8 characters and not 22 bytes.

Could anyone please guide on this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

simply you save your program as `utf-8`
and do as below

```
        String str= "मेरा नाम";
        System.out.println(str.length());
```

o/p = 8

Comment: 8 chars where every char is UTF-16 (two bytes). This is how Unicode text is stored in a String, as `char[]`.

Comment: I had not checked string length function, I was converting it into UTF-8 and then calculating the length. Your answer helped to try simply using string length on the text and I got the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The shortest "length" is in Unicode **code points**, as notion of numbered character, UTF-32.

***Correction:***
As @liudongmiao mentioned probably one should use:

```
int length = string.codePointCount(0, string.length);
```

In Java 8:

```
int length = (int) string.codePoints().count();
```

Prior javas:

```
int length(String s) {
   int n = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++n) {
       int cp = s.codePointAt(i);
       i += Character.charCount(cp);
   }
   return n;
}
```

A Unicode code point can be encoded in UTF-16 as one or two `char`s.

The same Unicode character might have diacritical marks. They can be written as separate code points: basic letter + zero or more diacritical marks. To normalize the string to one (C=) compressed code point:

```
string = java.text.Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFC);
```

BTW for database purposes, the UTF-16 length seems more useful:

```
string.length() // Number of UTF-16 chars, every char two bytes.
```

(In the example mentioned UTF-32 length == UTF-16 length.)

---

***A dump function***

A commenter had some unexpected result:

```
void dump(String s) {
   int n = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++n) {
       int cp = s.codePointAt(i);
       int bytes = Character.charCount(cp);
       i += bytes;
       System.out.printf("[%d] #%dB: U+%X = %s%n",
           n, bytes, cp, Character.getName(cp));
   }
   System.out.printf("Length:%d%n", n);
}
```

Comment: For prior java, you can use `s.codePointCount(0, s.length)`

Comment: For me the length() method in this answer produces a result of 10 for a string containing just five emoji (smileys), rather than the 5 I expected.

Comment: @OllieC: the function `length("...")` should indeed return 5. But maybe after every emoji there is some space or such. I'll add a dump method.

Comment: @JoopEggen There are no spaces between the emoji. It is a set of five consecutive smileys typed on an Android keyboard into an EditText and extracted using EditText.getText().toString() I'm not sure if that helps but I wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the http://rosettacode.org/wiki/String_length#Grapheme_Length_4:

```
import java.text.BreakIterator;

public class Grapheme {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printLength("møøse");
    printLength("");
    printLength("J̲o̲s̲é̲");
  }

  public static void printLength(String s) {
    BreakIterator it = BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance();
    it.setText(s);
    int count = 0;
    while (it.next() != BreakIterator.DONE) {
      count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Grapheme length: " + count+ " " + s);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Grapheme length: 5 møøse
Grapheme length: 7 
Grapheme length: 4 J̲o̲s̲é̲
```

What you are looking for is not string length bu grapeme length. It gives you the number of "visible" characters.

Comment: Works for me for emoji. A string with five emoji in it (five smileys, occupying ten characters in my test case) returns five (rather than the actual char count of 10).

Comment: Anyone knows how to do it for pure kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

`String.length()` actually returns the number of characters in a string encoded in UTF-16 (where two bytes are used to encode a character). However this should work for most UTF-8 chars too unless you have a character with an ASCII value greater than 127. If you want to do things by hand without encoding it to UTF-8, you can do something like this

```
public static int utf8Length(CharSequence sequence) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length(); i++) {
            char ch = sequence.charAt(i);
            if (ch <= 0x7F) {
                count++;
            } else if (ch <= 0x7FF) {
                count += 2;
            } else if (Character.isHighSurrogate(ch)) {
                count += 4;
                ++i;
            } else {
                count += 3;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Here's the [UTF-8 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#section-3).

Answer (score 1):

In UTF-8 String.length() returns number of characters. If you want to get number of bytes, you can use String.getBytes().length

For example:

String str = "アンドリューは本当に凄いですだと";

System.out.println(str.length()); // display 16 corresponding to 16 characters
System.out.println(str.getBytes().length); // display 48 corresponding to 48 bytes

Answer (score 0):

Rather than converting `password[0]` to a byte array you can simply run

`password[0].length();`

You can also convert the bytearray back to a string then run the lenght method on it as well.

```
    byte[] abc = password[0].getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET);
    String s1 = new String(abc, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(s1.length());
```