# Android - count the number of occurrences android

Tags: android

I have a code

```
String a = et1.getText().toString();
            int ad = 0;
            for(int i =0 ; i<a.length(); i++){
                if(a.charAt(i)== 'a'){
                    ad++;
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                    ad, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I gettext ok but i can't counts character 'a' in string. Can you help me?

Thanks

Another,
if i have String b = et2.getText().toString(); , b is special character, and i want count b in a string. How i can do?

Comment: [because `'A' != 'a'`](http://ideone.com/GvwVL8)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are sending an int to Toast.makeText() so it's looking for a resource id rather than displaying the int as a string.

```
    String a = "asjasuhuashu";
    int ad = 0;
    for(int i =0 ; i<a.length(); i++){
        if(a.charAt(i)== 'a'){
            ad++;
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(this,
            ad + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Edited as per Selvin suggestion.

Comment: I was editing an android app so I just pasted the code and looked :)

Comment: The problem with this question is that *but i can't counts character 'a' in string* can means anything :)

Comment: if i have String b = et2.getText().toString(); , b is special character, and i want count b in a string. How i can do?

Comment: You can find pointers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726723/find-out-number-of-characters-in-a-utf-8-string-in-java-android)

Answer (score 0):

you are passing Integer **ad** in as toast parameter which consider integer as resource id, use

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                    String.valueOf(ad), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

this is another way of calculating character count.

```
String s = "hghhaahghaa";
int count = s.length() - s.replaceAll("[aA]", "").length();
```

replace the character you want count of in above character **'a'** and **'A'** both will be counted.

if you want only character 'a' then replace **"[aA]"** with **"[a]"**.